# What's the short form for "as I told you before" in code review?

Tags: abbreviations

I'm working on a code review, I need leave a comment for the code. I'm trying to leave a comment the same as I left before it. I remember it might be "tilto" or something, but I forgot what exactly it is.

Anyone knows anything?

Thanks,
Jay Lin

Comment: "Toldya!" (Told you).

Comment: Seems to be some form of acronym, i.e. wysiwyg - what you see is what you get

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for the word "ditto".

From [Merriam Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ditto):

> **ditto**
>
> a thing mentioned previously or above —used to avoid repeating a word —often symbolized by inverted commas or apostrophes